# Import and export on SharePoint 2013

Tags: export, import

I created the new site collection. I had previously created a site collection in another server.

I want to move my old site collection's content to new site collection. How can I this? I searched on the net but I'm confused. How I can do export and import?

Comment: What you mean by you want to move pieces?

Comment: I want to move list list or page page to another site collection.

Comment: Ok in that case you can save the library as template and then upload it to list gallery. Create new list using that, then use it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not Site Collection backup and restore?

[Backup-SPSite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607901(v=office.15).aspx) and [Restore-SPSite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607788%28v=office.15%29.aspx) commands will help

Comment: Because my site collection's design different. And I want to move pieces @Arsalan

Answer (score 0):

There are two common options you have

1. Using Central Administration site
2. Using Powershell

**[Backup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748617(v=office.15).aspx)**

1. Start the SharePoint 2013 Management Shell.
2. At the Windows PowerShell command prompt, type the following command:

`Backup-SPSite -Identity <SiteCollectionGUIDorURL> -Path <BackupFile> [-Force] [-NoSiteLock] [-UseSqlSnapshot] [-Verbose]`

```
- <SiteCollectionGUIDorURL> is the ID or URL for the site collection you want to back up.
- <BackupFile> is the path to where the backup file is located.
```

**[Restore](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748655(v=office.15).aspx)**

1. Start the SharePoint 2013 Management Shell.
2. At the Windows PowerShell command prompt, type the following command:

`Restore-SPSite -Identity <SiteCollectionURL> -Path <Backup file> [-DatabaseServer <DatabaseServerName>] [-DatabaseName <ContentDatabaseName>] [-HostHeader <Host header>] [-Force] [-GradualDelete] [-Verbose]`

```
- <SiteCollectionURL> is URL for the site collection you want to restore.
- <DatabaseServerName> is name of the database server where the site collection resides.
- <ContentDatabaseName> is the name of the content database.
```